# Is there a way for me to pass to my view a context passed on to my template?

Tags: django, pandas, templates, view

I processed a DataFrame that I then passed on to my template as a context. I then used a form to move on to the next view. Is there a way to pass my DataFrame from the template on to the next view?
Here is my views code:

```
def clean(request):
  #processing on df
  return render(request, 'clean.html', {'conf': conf, 'num': newnum, 'df': df, 'corr': correl, 'target': nametar})
```

and here is my template that redirects to the correlation/ view:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load static %} {% block content %}

<p> {{num}} lines were dropped. Your dataset is now clean</p>
Here are the correlations of the features with the {{target}}, select the ones you want to drop. <br>
It is advised to delete the ones below 5% but you can keep them if necessary.
<form action = '{%url 'correlation'%}' method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for key, value in corr.items%} 
    {%if value != 1%}
    <input type = 'checkbox'>{{key}}- {{value}} <br>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
</select>
<p> Click the Next button to move on to the next phase "Transformation" </p>
<button type='submit' name='btn' id='btn' class='btn' >Next</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I pass my df from here to my view beside using a model?

Comment: You could store the df on the user's session? How large are these data frames because if they are large you will probably run into memory issues

Comment: Well my project's aim is to stay as general as possible and accept any dataset (and process it). Following that purpose, I cannot limit myself, and could indeed fall into memory issues. Is there any other way?